# calling the function consecutively returns same results

Tags: c, parsing

I am trying to extract urls from strings. So i've wrote soomething like this:

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#define BAD(x) (!(x) || (*(x) == '\0'))

static char *extract_link(char *string)
{
        static char url[512];
        int length;
        char *st;
        char *rl;
        char *rl2;
        url[0] = '\0';

        rl = strstr(string, "http://");
        if (!BAD(rl))
        {
                if (strstr(rl, " "))
                {
                        st = strstr(rl, " ");
                        length = strlen(rl) - strlen(st);
                        strncpy(url, rl, length);
                        url[length] = '\0';
                        return url;
                }
                return rl;
        }
        rl2 = strstr(string, "www.");
        if (!BAD(rl2))
        {
                if (strchr(rl2, ' '))
                {
                        st = strstr(rl2, " ");
                        length = strlen(rl2) - strlen(st);
                        strncpy(url, rl2, length);
                        url[length] = '\0';
                        return url;
                }
                return rl2;
        }
        return NULL;
}
int main()
{
        char *string1 = "We have a http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyP48_0C1DM&feature=featured here";
        char *string2 = "And We have a www.scribd.com/doc/52344388/JOINT-STATEMENT-ON-U-S-FUNDING-FOR-GLOBAL-CHILD-SURVIVAL-AND-MATERNAL-HEALTH or whatsoever";
        char *x = extract_link(string1), *y = extract_link(string2);
        if (!BAD(x))
                printf("%s\n", x);
        if (!BAD(y))
                printf("%s\n", y);
        return 0;
}
```

But i am getting same results over and over again. 
Output:

> www.scribd.com/doc/52344388/JOINT-STATEMENT-ON-U-S-FUNDING-FOR-GLOBAL-CHILD-SURVIVAL-AND-MATERNAL-HEALTH
>   www.scribd.com/doc/52344388/JOINT-STATEMENT-ON-U-S-FUNDING-FOR-GLOBAL-CHILD-SURVIVAL-AND-MATERNAL-HEALTH

It should be like this:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fuUTMJ8WRA&feature=feedrec_grec_index
>   www.scribd.com/doc/52344388/JOINT-STATEMENT-ON-U-S-FUNDING-FOR-GLOBAL-CHILD-SURVIVAL-AND-MATERNAL-HEALTH

So...
What i am doing wrong? What do you think about the code above. Soemthing i need to change or rewrite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does that because `extract_link()` overwrites a static buffer and returns a pointer to it.  Instead, return a pointer to the original string, or create a dynamically allocated buffer to point to.

There are tradeoffs with each approach.  For the one you used, you could leave it alone and change main to:

```
char *string1 = "We have a http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyP48_0C1DM&feature=featured here";
char *string2 = "And We have a www.scribd.com/doc/52344388/JOINT-STATEMENT-ON-U-S-FUNDING-FOR-GLOBAL-CHILD-SURVIVAL-AND-MATERNAL-HEALTH or whatsoever";
char *x = extract_link(string1);
if (!BAD(x))
      printf("%s\n", x);
x = extract_link(string2);
if (!BAD(x))
       printf("%s\n", x);
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you. What about the procedure? I mean, Can you say that the code is efficient? Or can be written more effectively?

Comment: Hard to say.  It is more of a specification issue than an efficiency thing.  Should `http://` be removed?  The answer depends on the use of the results.

Comment: Nope. If string contains a url that begins with http://, extracting it be more than enough. Same goes for urls that beings with www. So, long story short, they're meant to be leave alone. Just extracting is enough. I don't know about performance related stuff. So i need to ask you. Thank you.

Comment: Unless this code is being called more than 10,000 times per second, don't worry about its performance.